# How to prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x^n − y^n \text{ is divisible by } x − y$ using induction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm very stuck on this problem, which is an exercise from our course notes. Any clues or hints or a proof write up would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=(x+y)(x^n-y^n)-xy(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1})$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer tried rewriting $x^n$ as $k\cdot x$ per the definition of divisibility

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm confused as to how to factor (x-y) out of $x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}$

Comment: You don't *need* to factor $x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}$ into $m\left(x^n+y^n\right)$, nor use only one base case. It is easier with J.W.'s method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer with one $n$ value for the base case.

Induction step:  it's true for  $n=1$.

Now assume it's true for $n$; i.e., $x^{n}-y^{n}$ is divisible by $x-y$.

Since $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=x(x^{n}-y^{n})+y^{n}(x-y)$,

it follows that $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}$ is divisible by $x-y$.

Comment: But for this solution, if we had $n=0$ and the predicate to be defined as $x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}$, wouldn't this be invalid?

Comment: I don't think it was a problem, but I edited to avoid confusion

Comment: How did you get to factor out like that?

Comment: That's [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548349/how-to-factor-x-y-out-of-xn-yn-for-some-arbitrary-n-in-mathbbn)

Comment: Touche, but I wouldn't find seeing your work for it

Comment: Compare $(x^{n+1}-y^{n+1})/(x-y) $ and $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$ using the answer for the other question

Answer (score 1):

Base case:  it's true for $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Induction step:  assume it's true for $n-1$ and $n$;

i.e., $x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}$ and $x^n-y^n$ are divisible by $x-y$.

Then, since $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=(x+y)(x^n-y^n)-xy(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1})$,

it follows that $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}$ is divisible by $x-y$.

Comment: Would one base case work for this (assuming that we are using the IH of p(n))? Also I'm still confused as to how the factoring for $x-y$ out of $x^n-y^n$ works.

Comment: I used two $n$ values for the base case so I could for the induction step; $x-y$ divides $x^n-y^n$ by the induction hypothesis

Comment: That seems to almost be like strong induction, what if we just had the IH of p(n)?

Comment: I posted another answer that you might like more