# How to factor $x-y$ out of $x^n - y^n$ for some arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

As the title states. I don't quite understand how this factoring would work even though I'm fairly certain it can be done. Additionally, a follow up would be how does factoring $x^{n-1} - y^{n-1}$ out of $x^n - y^n$ work.

Comment: Are you familiar with polynomial division? Try dividing $(x^n-y^n)$ by $(x-y)$ and you should see some patterns emerging.

Comment: I haven't done that in awhile! I understand the summation answer below, but is there no conciser answer?

Comment: I doubt it. I don't think the sum simplifies further.

Comment: Ah ok. It does seem to be that way.

Comment: What do you mean by a *concise* answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117660/proving-xn-yn-x-yxn-1-xn-2-y-x-yn-2-yn-1)

Comment: @user2793618, that is the concise answer to this. It is a geometric series, but getting a closed form for that will result in the expression in the question. So there's no use and the sum is the only possible simplification.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a clean way to express it, i.e, no summations or some division trick, but this seems to be the best answer.

Comment: What makes you imagine it's possible to factor $x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}$ out of $x^n-y^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align} x^n - y^n
&= (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}) \\
&= (x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k}y^k
\end{align}$$
generalizing the identity $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Also not much but a side-comment to this. For $n$ being even. We have
$$x^n-y^n=\left(x-y\right)\left(x+y\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1}x^{\left(n-2-2k\right)}y^{2k}$$
For example,
$$x^6-y^6=\left(x-y\right)\left(x+y\right)\left(x^{4}+x^{2}y^{2}+y^{4}\right)$$