# ($a^n$+$b^n$) is divisible by ($a$+$b$) when $n$ is odd (proof by induction)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am trying to prove that ($a^n$+$b^n$) is divisible by ($a$+$b$) when $n$ is odd.

I start off by checking for $n$ = $1$, and find that it is true for $n$ = $1$

Now I assume that it is true for $n$ = ($2k$-$1$),

i.e [$a^{2k-1}$+$b^{2k-1}$] is divisible by ($a$+$b$)

Finally, I proceed to checking for $n$ = ($2k$+$1$) :

$=$ {$a^{2k+1}$+$b^{2k+1}$}

$=$ {$a^2$$a^{2k-1}$+$b^2$$b^{2k-1}$}

Now I don’t understand how to prove that {$a^2$$a^{2k-1}$+$b^2$$b^{2k-1}$} is divisible by ($a$+$b$) based on my assumption earlier.

Appreciate any help

Comment: @πtimese You can do $a^2a^{2k-1}+b^2b^{2k-1}=a^2a^{2k-1}+a^2b^{2k-1}-a^2b^{2k-1}+b^2b^{2k-1}=a^2(a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1})-b^{2k-1}(a^2-b^2)$. Here, the first term $a^2(a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1})$ is divisible by $a+b$ by the induction hypothesis, and the second $b^{2k-1}(a^2-b^2)=b^{2k-1}(a+b)(a-b)$ too.

Comment: @lepidon:  again I posted an answer that matches your comment before I saw your comment!

Comment: Compare [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548318/how-to-prove-forall-n-in-mathbbn-xn-%e2%88%92-yn-text-is-divisible-by-x-%e2%88%92-y)

Comment: @lepidon thanks a lot. That helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the induction step *in this proof* to work, we need to check two base cases: $n = 1$ is obvious as you said, and for $n=3$:

$$ a+b\ |\ (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = a^3+b^3$$

Since we proved two base cases, now we can assume it is true for $n=2k-3$ and $n=2k-1$, that means:

$$a+b\ |\ a^{2k-3}+b^{2k-3}\ \wedge\ a+b\ |\ a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1}$$

Therefore:

$$a+b\ |\ (a^2+b^2)(a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1})-a^2b^2(a^{2k-3}+b^{2k-3}) = a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$$

we get that

$$a+b \ | \ a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$$

Comment: Need? One could, but there is no real need.

Comment: For his proof, it's needed, because of the exponent of $2k-3$

Comment: @lepidon, your idea also uses $P(1)$. The point is $P(2k-1)$ by itself does not imply $P(2k+1)$

Comment: @Atticus What I am saying is that it is not a need of the problem to have to check $P(3)$, as a result doesn't need to be proven by this specific argument.

Comment: @Atticus Can we assume that it is true for $n$ = $2k$-$1$ and $n$ = $2k$-$3$ both? I thought we generally assume that it is true for $n$ = $k$ (which is $2k$-$1$ in this case), and then we prove for $n$ = $k$+$1$ (which is $2k$+$1$ in this case) ?

Comment: @πtimese:  cf. [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction)

Comment: @DavidPeterson A need of a particular line of argument is not necessarily a need of all possible proofs of a given result. What I said is that the statement "For the induction step to work, we need to check two base cases." can be read as saying that it is a requirement of the result, but this is not true for this result.

Comment: @lepidon, using my idea *needs* it. What I wrote is true up to the semantics. The fact that your idea does not need $P(3)$ specifically, I congratulate you for it.

Comment: @πtimese, for the induction step, we can assume as many cases are true as we've proven in the base step.

Comment: I know. But precision is crucial in mathematics. Since the phrase that you used means something different than what you intended and since the literal meaning is false, it is good to clarify such that someone who is learning induction doesn't get the wrong idea.

Comment: @lepidon, I edited. I hope it is sufficiently precise now.

Comment: @Atticus So if I prove three base cases, I can assume three different cases to be true, and use them for my proof later?

Comment: @πtimese, Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Atticus thanks for clarifying. Can you briefly explain why you proved two base cases? You said using your idea needs it. I still don't quite understand why you had to prove two base cases for the induction step to work. Is it because you later assumed two different cases to be true?

Comment: @πtimese, I added some detail. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Atticus So basically you proved two base cases because you wanted to assume two cases to be true, to use them in the proof?

Comment: @πtimese, Yes, thats pretty much it. But it's not that I wanted, for the identity I used, I needed both the cases $2k-1$ and $2k-3$, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Atticus I understand it now, thanks a lot. One last question : When we assume two or more cases to be true, they must be for successive values of $n$, right? For example, in this case, the two cases assumed to be true were for $n$ = $2k$-$3$ and $n$ = $2k$-$1$ ?

Comment: @πtimese, Yes, that's true.

Comment: @Atticus thanks again. It was really helpful

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=a^2(a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1})-b^{2k-1}(a^2-b^2)$$